# Enforce valid react props in typescript with enums

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I've got this button component

```
import React from 'react';

enum ColorShape {
  'blue',
  'green',
  'white',
  'grey',
  'black',
}

enum SizeShape {
  'normal',
  'small',
}

interface PropsShape {
  text: string;
  color: ColorShape;
  size: SizeShape;
}

function Button({ text, color }: PropsShape) {
  return (
    <button className='Button'>
      {text} {color}
    </button>
  );
}

export { Button, ColorShape, SizeShape };
```

And I'm using it live this

```
import { Button, ColorShape, SizeShape } from '../components/button';
...
<Button text='Log In'color='blue' size='normal' />
```

I've read the docs but I'm clearly missing something, I want to make sure the props are one the enum values.

The error I get is

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ColorShape'.ts(2322)
button.tsx(18, 3): The expected type comes from property 'color' which is declared here on type 'I
```

Comment: `color:ColorShape='blue'` I've never seen this!? Is this new? Or is this just invalid syntax?

Comment: no I've clearly fudged it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong syntax, try this:

```js
enum ColorShape {
  BLUE = 'blue',
  GREEN = 'green',
  WHITE = 'white',
  GREY = 'grey',
  BLACK = 'black',
};

enum SizeShape {
  NORMAL = 'normal',
  SMALL = 'small',
};
```

```js
import { Button, ColorShape, SizeShape } from '../components/button';
...
<Button text='Log In'color={ColorShape.BLUE} size={SizeShape.NORMAL} />
```

Comment: That got me a big step closer, thank you, I'm now getting my linter blowing up saying that all the values are defined but not used with `no-unused-vars`

Comment: you may encounter the same issue as this, can check:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1197

Comment: yes that got it i added     "no-unused-vars": "off", "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error"] to eslint, thank you

Comment: is enum the best way of checking the string is valid?

Comment: if you have only a few string options, then you can just do this:


```javascript
interface PropsShape {
  text: string;
  color:   'blue' | 'green',
  size: 'smal' | 'normal';
}
```


```javascript
<Button text='Log In' color='blue' size='normal' />
```

IMO using enums is good for checking strings.